# Create Table from Summary() in R

Tags: r, dataframe

used the generic Summary() function to get some data. Now i want to display some of the summary data into a table and then knit into pdf. How to I create a table on the results from calling the Summary() function?

Using TeX, kableExtra and ggplot2.

```
summary(segmentdata)
summary(subset(segmentdata, Segment == "Suburb mix"))
summary(subset(segmentdata, Segment == "Urban hip"))
summary(subset(segmentdata, Segment == "Travelers"))
summary(subset(segmentdata, Segment == "Moving up"))
```

E.g. data

age           gender              income            kids         ownHome
Min.   :20.00   Length:300         Min.   :-13292   Min.   :0.000   Length:300
1st Qu.:32.75   Class :character   1st Qu.: 38122   1st Qu.:0.000   Class :character
Median :39.00   Mode  :character   Median : 51134   Median :1.000   Mode  :character
Mean   :40.59                      Mean   : 50259   Mean   :1.163
3rd Qu.:47.00                      3rd Qu.: 63001   3rd Qu.:2.000
Max.   :70.00                      Max.   :139679   Max.   :5.000
subscribe           Segment
Length:300         Length:300
Class :character   Class :character
Mode  :character   Mode  :character

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please check the [How to make a great R reproducible example, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Additionally, you didn't mention which tex editor you are using (Microsoft Word, TeX?).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow. It's a good practice when posting a question to provide actual data with a reproducible example so contributors can help you. `reprex` package is recommended with `R`.

I'll give you an answer based on what I think you want to achieve. I used the `iris` data set as an example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

vars <- iris %>% names()
iris %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%       # subset data
  map_dfr(summary) %>%                  # apply summary to variables
  add_column(vars = vars, .before = 1)  # add variable names

#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>   vars  Min.  `1st Qu.` Median Mean  `3rd Qu.` Max.  setosa versicolor virginica
#>   <chr> <tab> <table>   <tabl> <tab> <table>   <tab>  <int>      <int>     <int>
#> 1 Sepa.. 4.3   4.8       5.0    5.006 5.200     5.8       NA         NA        NA
#> 2 Sepa.. 2.3   3.2       3.4    3.428 3.675     4.4       NA         NA        NA
#> 3 Peta.. 1.0   1.4       1.5    1.462 1.575     1.9       NA         NA        NA
#> 4 Peta.. 0.1   0.2       0.2    0.246 0.300     0.6       NA         NA        NA
#> 5 Spec..  NA    NA        NA       NA    NA      NA       50          0         0
```

For more detail on the process, check out the function's documentation.

For the `kableExtra` output, add `kbl() %>% kable_styling()` at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help not sure I understand though. Maybe provided too little information. I am trying to do a summary of a subset as well and then do a table in kableExtra of that. Dont understand the syntax for above to summary with subset.

Comment: `filter()` function will do the same job as `subset`. Let me know if my edit to the answer helps you

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to download a package for that? Getting: "Error in map_dfr(., summary) : could not find function "map_dfr""

Comment: Yes, if you don't have packages installed you'll have to do `install.packages()` or install them via the `Packages` tab in the RStudio IDE.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work, had to update rlang though.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Im new to StackOverflow, how do I accept your answer?

Comment: There should be a tick mark below the down arrow at the left of the question box.